# Proving an inequality of modulus of complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $x,y,z$ be distinct complex numbers such that $$y=tx+(1-t)z$$ ; where $t \in (0,1)$

Prove that $$\frac{|z|-|y|}{|z-y|} \geq \frac{|z|-|x|}{|z-x|} \geq \frac{|y|-|x|}{|y-x|} $$

I tried this question by finding $t$ in terms of $x,y,z$. But I'm getting an inequality which doesn't lead to the answer.

$$|t|= \frac{|y-z|}{|x-z|} $$

So we have  $$0 \leq|y-z|\leq|x-z|$$

Now it is clear that $$0 \leq|y|-|z|\leq|x-z|$$

After this ? I;m stuck. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|z-y|=|-tx+tz|=t|z-x|$.  Meanwhile, by the triangle inequality,
$$|z|-|y|\geq|z|-t|x|-(1-t)|z|=t(|z|-|x|)$$
and so we now have
$$\frac{|z|-|y|}{|z-y|}\geq\frac{t(|z|-|x|)}{t|z-x|}=\frac{|z|-|x|}{|z-x|}.$$
The remaining inequality should be similar.